# Prove that $v$ is a linear combination of $v_1,...,v_n$ if it is a linear combination of $w_1,...,w_m$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

How should I do this? Should I use the definition of linear independence?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually this is completely independant of any consideration of linear independance of the two family of vectors given. You just need to write down what it means to be a linear combination and the result will follow.

Every $w_i$ is a linear combination of $v_1,\dots,v_n$, thus there real numbers $\alpha_{ij}$ such that
$$w_i=\sum_{j=1}^n \alpha_{ij}v_j,\quad \forall 1\leq i\leq m.$$

Now $v$ is a linear combination of $w_1,\dots,w_m$, thus there exist real numbers $\beta_i$ ($1\leq i\leq m$) such that
$$v=\sum_{i=1}^m\beta_i w_i.$$

Now if you replace every $w_i$ by its expression given in the first equation, you get
$$v=\sum_{i=1}^m\beta_i \left(\sum_{j=1}^n \alpha_{ij}v_j\right),$$and because addition in vector space is commutative and associative, and because of the distributivity and "associativity" of scalar multiplication, this can be rewritten as
$$v=\sum_{i=1}^m\beta_i \left(\sum_{j=1}^n \alpha_{ij}v_j\right)=\sum_{j=1}^n\left(\sum_{i=1}^m \alpha_{ij}\beta_i\right)v_j,$$
which shows that $v$ is a linear combination of $v_1,\dots ,v_n$.

If all this seems unclear to you, try to write down some small examples to see how it works in a particular case.